# How To Pass State Update To Custom Render Loop In React's `useEffect`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I often encounter the situation that I build a `window.requestAnimationFrame` based render loop, but want some states to be exchanged with the inside of the loop.  There are a few ways to accommplish that, but I'm not sure which on is the best.  My setup usually looks something like this:

```js
function Animation({someState}) {
  const loopDataRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    //do something initialization work for the renderloop, e.g. getContext, etc.
    let frame;
    const loop = (cts) => {
      frame = window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
      //do some loop work using someState and loopDataRef.current
    }
    loop();
    return () => window.cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
  }, []);
}
```

Note that using `someState` inside the loop will always use the value from the last ran of the effect, not necessarily the current value.  Here are the some obvious solutions:

- I can put `someState` in the dependency array of `useEffect`, this way the loop will be restarted whenever the state changes.  But if the initialization is expensive, for example with WebGL where I create all the textures there and compile the shaders, it doesn't seem very elegant.
- I can use two effects, one for the initialization of the loop itself, and another one for just the loop, which stops and starts on every state change.  But I still think, ideally an animation loop should run until it stops and not stop/start in between.
- Another solution with two effects, but this time I do `const someStateRef = useRef()` and then create an effect with `someState` in its dependency array which just writes `someState` into `someStateRef.current` so I can use it inside the loop.  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-loop-vfnk7c) is an example where I implement this.  Alternatively one can write `someState` into `someStateRef.current` on every render, without another effect.  Looks very performant, but not really elegant.

What's the most React way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the 3rd option that you [already implemented](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-loop-vfnk7c), as it looks exactly like [one example from the React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often) (3rd code block):

```js
function Example(props) {
  // Keep latest props in a ref.
  const latestProps = useRef(props);
  useEffect(() => {
    latestProps.current = props;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      // Read latest props at any time
      console.log(latestProps.current);
    }

    const id = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []); // This effect never re-runs
}
```

(replacing `set/clearInterval` with `request/cancelAnimationFrame`)

For completeness: The first two options suffer from the flaws you mentioned, and writing `someState` to `someStateRef.current` on every render without another effect is not recommended.

> Avoid reading and updating refs during rendering because this makes your component’s behavior difficult to predict and understand.

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)